# What apt package installs "ip addr" command?

Tags: apt

How can I install the package for "networks" on a very think ubuntu image in docker?

I need to add this package in an image using a Dockerfile

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I found the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51834978/ip-command-is-missing-from-ubuntu-docker-image

`# apt update`
`# apt install iproute2 -y`

My docker container although didn't have iproute2 package installed, the internet connection was active.

Comment: here is the iproute2 for download manually: https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/iproute2/download

Answer (score 14):

`ip` program is a part of `iproute2` package

```
user@ubuntu18:~$ dpkg -S ip | grep '/sbin/ip$'
user@ubuntu18:~$ iproute2: /sbin/ip
```

Comment: Too long and complicated, use `dpkg -S $(which ip)` instead.

Comment: how can I install the package, downloading it manually and copying it into the container?

Comment: @N0rbert Thanks, but I get `dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/sbin/ip`; I think that this is because the thing is a link to `/bin/ip`

Comment: And `readlink -f` doesn't work either as it seems that `/bin` gets translated to `/usr/bin` which isn't in the package :(